# AI Techniques for Simple Strategy Games

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-development

Some of the strategies I can think of for implementing an AI player for simple 2-player games like Tic-tac-toe, Connect 4 etc. are:

- Random play
- Use of a heuristic (e.g. play the center or corners when possible)
- Minimax
- Monte Carlo methods

Are there any other approaches which are commonly used please?

Comment: Down votes without information are valueless, IMO.

Comment: This is very broad and also lacks some work on your end (imho): `simple 2-player game` is a bad description as there are simple 2-player games where your zero-sum assumption won't hold and minimax will fail. `Random play` is also a form of `Monte Carlo methods` (which would be different if the latter would be the more specific `Monte Carlo Tree Search`). It probably also does not help, that for both examples perfect-play strategies are known without the need for brute-force search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of approaches you have is a reasonable start - especially for two-player perfect information games. If you allow a broader range of games you get a broader set of algorithms:

- Learning algorithm (either reinforcement learning or supervised learning) can be used for play on their own, although they are often combined with some type of search for even stronger game play.
- Expectiminimax is used in games with chance elements but no hidden information.
- Counter-factual Regret (CFR) is used for computing Nash equilibria in games like Poker with hidden information. (Fictitious play is a similar alternate.)
- Perfect-Information Monte-Carlo (PIMC) is an approximation algorithm for games with imperfect information that can be used on top of other search algorithms. This is usually used for trick-based card games.
- Multi-player games are usually based on the max^n algorithm instead of minimax. (There is a similar variant of MCTS.)

When you get to more complex games, there are a broader range of algorithms available because they need to deal with the complexities of a specific game in different ways.